# Query RecordType WHERE SObjectType LIKE does not work

Tags: soql, query, record-type

I'm trying to select RecordType by SObjectType but I would like to skip namespaces, so I'm trying to use LIKE.

```
[SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = 'Product'
                           AND SObjectType LIKE '%Thing__c']
```

Eclipse won't let me save it:

> Save error: invalid operator on id field

What makes no sense to me, since `AND SObjectType = 'Thing__c'` works just fine. And of course 'Thing__c' is not an Id.

I tried `SObjectType.Name`, but there is no relationship like that.

Am I missing something? Is there a documentation about this behavior? any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note sure why SObjectType is treated as an ID field. In the [RecordType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm) details SObjectType field is mentioned as a picklist which holds all the objects. may be its internally storing all the object references..

one option I can think of is to get your required object names into a string array or list and use IN operator

```
List<String> objNames = new List<String>();
[SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = 'Product'
                           AND SObjectType IN :objNames];
```

you can get the object names you are interested in by using either describe methods or a query like

```
[SELECT  QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition where QualifiedApiName like '%Thing__c']
```

Answer (score 2):

SObjectType is a lookup field, despite having non-ID values in it. There is a magic show going on, complete with smoke and mirrors, that makes it easier to work with record types. Other tables are more honest about it, such as [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm), which includes a TableEnumOrId field, which will show values like Account or 01I50000000NMZ8 (a custom object Id). You'll want to either perform a global describe, or call the tooling API to find the objects you're interested in. There's no straight-forward way to use LIKE on the SObjectField that I'm aware of, since no SOQL query will give you a list of object names.